# pytest django load database data from yaml file

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I have dumped data from my development environment using dumpdata django command into a yaml file.

I am using pytest framework and need to achieve the following scenario:

- During start of a pytest session -> that is when I run pytest from command line, the data from yaml file should be loaded into my test database

Is there any plugin or hook which I can use to achieve the above ?

I am using python 3.8, pytest 6.2.4, pytest-django 4.40, Django 3.0.5

Comment: Why do you want to load this data before running your tests? It’s usually a good idea to create the data that you want to test against as part of the test

Comment: I have some data in dev environment which i have tested  my app manually. I want to write tests for the same. Creating data will be time consuming and error prone as I have some rock solid data in yaml.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes can you please tell how i can achieve the same in pytest

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the `pytest-django` package then you can load Django data fixtures for your tests by providing a [`django_db_setup` fixture](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#populate-the-test-database-if-you-don-t-use-transactional-or-live-server) pytest fixture in `conftest.py`

```
import pytest

from django.core.management import call_command

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        call_command('loaddata', 'my_fixture.yaml')
```